# Inject mockService into an controller initialized from a directive

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I want to unit test (karma) a directive, that has a controller with injected services.

See following code:

```
angular
    .module('webkr')
    .directive('userChangePassword', userChangePassword)
    .directive('compareTo', compareTo);


  /** @ngInject */
  function userChangePassword() {
    var directive = {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {},
      templateUrl: 'app/components/account/user_change_password/user_change_password.html',
      controller: changePasswordController,
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      bindToController: true
    };

    return directive;

    /** @ngInject */
    function changePasswordController($log, User, toastr) {
      var _this = this;

      //properties
      _this.formModel = {
        password: null,
        oldPassword: null,
        passwordRepetition: null
      };
      _this.formDefinition = {
        oldPassword: {
          name: 'oldPassword',
          label: 'Altes Passwort',
          placeholder: 'Altes Passwort',
          error: 'old password is required.'
        },
        password: {
          name: 'password',
          label: 'Neues Passwort',
          placeholder: 'Neues Passwort',
          error: 'new password is required.'
        },
        passwordRepetition: {
          name: 'passwordRepetition',
          label: 'Passwort bestätigen',
          placeholder: 'Passwort bestätigen',
          errorRequired: 'old password is required.',
          errorInvalid: 'Confirmation password is not equal new password.'
        }
      };

      //methods

      /**
       * cancel change password procedure
       */
      _this.cancelChangePassword = function () {
        //clean form data

        _this.changePasswordForm.$setPristine();
      };
      /**
       * submit change password
       */
      _this.submitPasswordChange = function () {
        if (_this.changePasswordForm.$invalid) {
          return;
        }

        User.changePassword(_this.formModel).then(function () {
          toastr.info('Password changed', JSON.stringify(_this.formModel));
          _this.cancelChangePassword();
        }, function (err) {
          toastr.error('Can`t change password');
          $log.error(err);
        });
      };
    }
  }
```

My unit test accordingly:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  describe('directive user_change_password', function () {
    var el, compile, rootScope, controller, mockUserService;

    beforeEach(function () {
      mockUserService = jasmine.createSpyObj('User', ['changePassword'])
      module('webkr', 'ngMockE2E')
    });

    beforeEach(inject(function ($compile, $rootScope, $controller, $q, $log, toastr) {
      compile = $compile;
      rootScope = $rootScope;

      //Service routes used in controller
      mockUserService.changePassword.and.returnValue($q.when("result"));

      //Compile element
      el = compile("<user-change-password></user-change-password>")(rootScope);
      rootScope.$digest();

      //Init controller
      controller = el.controller("userChangePassword", {
        $log: $log,
        User: mockUserService,
        toastr: toastr
      });

      //Spy on the form
      spyOn(controller.changePasswordForm, '$setPristine')

    }));

    it('should be compiled', function () {
      expect(el.html()).not.toEqual(null);
    });
  });
})();
```

Somehow, the controller is not correctly initialized. When i remove the object (`{$log:$log,User:mockUserService,toastr:toastr}`) everything is working fine. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mocking controller dependencies is applicable to controller-only specs that involve `$controller`.

`el.controller` is getter method and [has only 1 parameter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#methods):

> controller(name) - retrieves the controller of the current element or
>   its parent.

At this moment

```
  //Init controller
  controller = el.controller("userChangePassword", { ... });
```

the directive was compiled and its controller was instantiated, that's why its instance can be retrieved.

To mock a service when testing directive controllers stick to mocking on injector level:

```
beforeEach(module('webkr', 'ngMockE2E', function ($provide) {
  $provide.factory('User', function ($q) {
     return { changePassword: jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue($q.when("result")) };
  });      
}));
```